# Issues in Web Application with PDF Portfolios

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, web-applications, microsoft-edge, acrobat

I have a web application that displays PDF's.  In IE, it uses the Adobe Acrobat viewer.  In Chrome and Edge, they use their own PDF viewer.  For regular PDF's, everything works well.

For Portfolio PDFs, IE is fine since it uses the Adobe Acrobat viewer.  In Chrome and Edge, they don't view the portfolios, and we are currently asking users to download the file and open in Adobe Acrobat.

Is there any setting/change to get Chrome and/or Edge to be able to display a portfolio PDF?  Or is there any 3rd party control that I can add to the web application to use it to display the portfolio PDF?

We also have a similar issue with certain PDF forms and PDF's with signatures in Chrome and Edge.  I'm hoping that using a 3rd party control or any setting/changes could alleviate this as well.

Comment: Do you mean you want to see the [Table of contents](https://imgur.com/a/Wsn7JAu) or [page tabs](https://imgur.com/a/E93BRiQ) with the pdfs? If I am misunderstanding, can you please try to provide a screenshot of the issue? If possible please try to provide the sample pdf file that can help us to reproduce the issue on our end. It can help us better understand the issue. For more information regarding PDF reader in the Edge browser, you can visit this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-pdf)

Comment: When I try to view a PDF Portfolio in Edge, I get a message 'For the best experience, open this PDF portfolio in Acrobat X or Acrobat Reader X, or later.  I currently have XI Pro installed.  But I need to view the PDF portfolio inside the web application in Edge (and Chrome).

Answer (score 1):

enable this in Chrome, go to

chrome://flags/#pdf-portfolio

Comment: version 117 is what I currently have (update in chrome by going to the three dots at top right of browser, hover over 'help'and click on 'About Google Chrome'.  From there you should be able to update and relaunch Chrome browser).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

you said,"`I get a message 'For the best experience, open this PDF portfolio in Acrobat X or Acrobat Reader X, or later.`"

I try to search about this issue and found that this is a **Cover sheet** for your portfolio PDF that gets display when the user tries to open the portfolio PDF in an application that does not support the portfolio PDF.

Ref: [For the best experience, open this PDF portfolio in Acrobat X or Adobe Reader X, or later merged PDF](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat/for-the-best-experience-open-this-pdf-portfolio-in-acrobat-x-or-adobe-reader-x-or-later-merged-pdf/m-p/10722735)

You had asked,"`Is there any setting/change to get Chrome and/or Edge to be able to display a portfolio PDF? Or is there any 3rd party control that I can add to the web application to use it to display the portfolio PDF?`"

Both MS Edge and Google Chrome browsers do not support viewing portfolio PDF, so there is no setting/change available that can help you view portfolio PDF in Edge or Chrome browser.

I am not aware of any third-party control, I suggest you raise a new question about this on [Adobe Support Community](https://community.adobe.com/). As portfolio PDF supported by Acrobat reader they might give you some helpful information.

Comment: Thanks, and thats what I thought.  IE used the Acrobat component to view PDF's which included PDF Portfolios, and that still works fine.  Do you know if there is any way to supersede the Edge or Chrome PDF viewer to force the Acrobat component to display PDF's and PDF Portfolios in Edge/Chrome?

Comment: At present, there is no way available to forcefully display the Portfolio PDF in the Edge or Chrome browser. I suggest you press the `ALT + SHIFT + I` key in the Edge browser window and try to provide your feedback regarding this feature request to Microsoft. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally Browsers could not display Portfolios since Netscape plug-ins were retired, and non Acrobat Readers desktop PDF readers may have variable abilities or simply require the imbedded PDFs be opened as separate Windows.
[image]
[image]

Currently Main release of Edge v117 offers Limited ability to view XFA files via edge://flags but not yet Portfolios

[image]

### **As pointed out by @rob-ashcroft**

Currently Chrome v117 can extract the files and then you can view them too like a desktop viewer.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In Microsoft Edge you can enable the "Internet Explorer mode".
[reload page in internet explorer mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-local-site-list)

It will enable viewing PDF portfolios in Microsoft Edge.

It works for me