# Extract individual PDF from a portfolio of multiple PDF documents

Tags: javascript, php, pdf

I have a web application built with PHP and JS.
In this app I make different operations with certain files and i encounter the next problem:

The user needs to upload in my app a PDF file which is a portfolio/package of multiple PDF documents (AcroForm). So the problem is that I don't know how to individually extract each PDF document from the portfolio (I want to read each PDF file separate, otherwise i can't).
This is where I get stuck and I don't know how de-structure this collection of PDF's.
If you have any idea how to do this please let me know.

Here is the code that I write to extract the data from a single PDF, it is working for a single PDF file, that's why I need to de-structure the collection of PDF's (I use pdflib to extract the data from a single PDF doc)

```
// get the values from the uploaded PDF form (AcroForm) when the form is submited and send them to the server
document.getElementById('form')?.addEventListener('submit', async e => {
         e.preventDefault();

         const { PDFDocument, PDFTextField, PDFDropdown, PDFRadioGroup, PDFCheckBox, PDFOptionList } = PDFLib;
         const file = document.getElementById('file').files[0];
         const data = await readData(file);
         const PDFDoc = await PDFDocument.load(data);
         const form = PDFDoc.getForm();
         const fields = form.getFields();
         // get the values from the fields and send them to the server...
});

      // get the file data
      function readData(file) {
         return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.onload = e => resolve(e.target.result);
            fileReader.onerror = reject;
            fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
         })
      }
```

Example with the PDF portfolio/collection (in the left side are the PDF documents that I need to extract them separately in my app):
[PDF portfolio example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KT7lN.jpg)

Comment: so, you don't care if the pdf is "split" on the client or on the server? as long as someone writes the code for you?

Comment: Show the code you've got so far and explain specifically where you're running into this problem.

Answer (score 0):

PDF Portfolios are a nested "Collection" of PDFs generally shown as attachments with a cover sheet. Very much an Adobe Reader specific feature, that some utilities browsers or other readers handle a variety of ways.

They are to be discouraged , since a means to hide unwanted run time data  within the outer wrap. Also as problematic for other applications to handle as SWFlash or 3D or XFA dynamic forms . All of which diversify from plain and simple archive / printer / displayable / read aloud content.

For Command Line users, cross platform, simplest is use Poppler PDFdetach.

For Browser users the newest Chrome v117 can be used to allow extraction for reading but for security reasons does not (should not) run those contents directly. see [Issues in Web Application with PDF Portfolios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66745871/issues-in-web-application-with-pdf-portfolios/77115710#77115710)