# Can we open a XFA based PDF form in a web browser which is hosted over sharepoint?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, browser, adobe, microsoft-edge

When i try to open a outlook link which re-directs to open a XFA pdf which is hosted in sharepoint .
When the XFA pdf is opened over the browser i receive a error message :
Please wait :
If this message is not eventually replaced by the proper contents of the document, your PDf viewer may not be able to display this of doc.

I enabled XFA support in edge://flags.

Can we open XFA pdf over browser?

Comment: XFA = XML Forms Architecture, it isn't PDF at all it is an XML-based form embedded inside a PDF file. The PDF file is nothing more than a page which contains the message you describe (it is informative, not an error message). Adobe Acrobat is one of the very few consumers able to process XFA, for the simple reason that XFA **isn't** PDF. Clearly your browser can't handle XFA natively so your only hope of reading (and filling out) an XFA form is to get a browser extension, such as Adobe Acrobat) which can.

Comment: Hi, may I know whether your issue has been solved or not? Have you checked my answer below?

Answer (score 0):

XFA comes in multiple variations (One reason to avoid using it as) some will work in some readers and others will ONLY work in LiveCycle or Acrobat.

Your Question is will browsers open such files and thus the  answer is it depends which version of which Browser.

A related issue is how other Adobe File embedment's are handled, So for Portfolios (PDF embed inside PDF) Chrome version 117 and above should handle some. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/77115710/10802527

For XFA in Edge it is classed Experimental and Microsoft have their own variations but switched on in my Edge I still see
[image]

Same with Current version 117 Chrome (the option is not offered)

However Firefox (older 102 as not yet updated can use them) has a minor problem with Logo permissions. I have seen FireFox attempt some Published .Gov forms that were a mess of a rendering as poorly designed purely for "In House" Acrobat Online usage.

[image]

This should say it varies as 1 of 3 or 1 of 4 pages  (dynamic XFA is variable numbers of pages) However as useless it does not matter.
[image]

So this Static XFA form opens **against the sites advice** in Chrome an thus does not work as intended , which is a common problem with XFA in general when not running with an Adobe Server for import export.

XFA should be classed as Adobe Proprietary and are not in the ISO Standard  for IMHO a darn good reason.

[image]

### Answer

**Bottom Line is :
if a XFA enhanced PDF is plain enough it may render in Edge but not be Forms Data File workable.**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

PDF reader in Edge doesn't support XFA. You can refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-pdf#constraints):

> XML Forms Architecture (XFA), is a legacy format of forms that isn't supported in Microsoft Edge.

If you want to open XFA in Edge, you can try to install some PDF extensions such as Adobe Acrobat.